# declare a struct in header as a typedef

Tags: c, struct

I'm trying to define a structure as a typedef in a header file and use it in many sources. I found a similar answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223771/repeated-multiple-definition-errors-from-including-same-header-in-multiple-cpps) but I'm not sure if a typedef can be defined as extern. Also `msg_encoded` should have a default value.

```
// lib.h

#ifndef lib_h
#define lib_h

struct msg_encoded_s
{
    uint8_t msg[10];
    int length;
} msg_encoded_default = {{0}, 0};

typedef struct msg_encoded_s msg_encoded;

#endif

// lib.c

#include "lib.h"

msg_encoded some_var;

// main.c

# include "lib.h"
int main(){
    msg_encoded some_other_var;
}
```

> main.o:(.bss.msg_encoded_default+0x0): multiple definition of
>   `msg_encoded_default'

Comment: [Variable declaration in a header file](//stackoverflow.com/a/1164190)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Should I make both `msg_encoded_default` and `msg_encoded` extern?

Comment: If you are including that header file into more than one source module in your program, then each one is defining `msg_encoded_default`. You should define `msg_encoded_default` in one source module, then `extern` it in the header (`extern msg_encoded msg_encoded_default;`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid "multiple definition" error for global constants?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24717066/how-to-avoid-multiple-definition-error-for-global-constants)

Comment: The error is not caused by the typedef. It's caused by the `msg_encoded_default` variable.

Comment: Since you have the typedef, you could declare the `msg_encoded_default` variable using the typedef. E.g. declare `extern msg_encoded msg_encoded_default;` in "lib.h", and `msg_encoded msg_encoded_default = {{0}, 0};` in "lib.c".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "declaration" like

```
struct msg_encoded_s {
   ...
} msg_encoded_default;
```

is actually both (1) a definition of a `struct`-type named `msg_encoded_s` and (2) the *definition* of a variable of this type named `msg_encoded_default.

Hence, if you include this header file in separate translation units, then you will redefine a variable named `msg_encoded_default`, which is not allowed.

To overcome this, write a header like...

```
typedef struct msg_encoded_s
{
    uint8_t msg[10];
    int length;
} msg_encoded;

extern msg_encoded msg_encoded_default;
```

An in exactly one translation unit write:

```
#include "myheader.h"
msg_encoded msg_encoded_default = {{0}, 0};
```

In all other translation units just write...

```
#include "myheader.h"
...
int test = msg_encoded_default.length;  // or something like this
```

Comment: Thank you, Why you set the default value in `.c` and not `.h`?

Comment: The default value is set where the variable is *defined*, while `extern  msg_encoded msg_encoded_default;` is just a *declaration*

Comment: +1 for good explain difference between declaration and definition of variable in C. 
[see Johnathan Leffler post] ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/1433387/7508077)